# Javascript validate all radio buttons if checked

Tags: validation, radio-button

Im so dumb in javascript, I would like to ask your help about radio button validation. I have 3 set of questions, each has 3 radio buttons. I want to validate if all the 3 questions have been answered or checked.

Thanks in advance

Here is the code I have tested, it only validates 1 radiobutton

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function validateForm() {
    var radios = document.querySelectorAll("#option1, #option2, #option3, #option4, #option5, #option6");
    var formValid = false;

    var i = 0;
    while (!formValid && i < radios.length) {
        if (radios[i].checked) formValid = true;
        i++;        
    }

    if (!formValid) alert("Must check some option!");
    return formValid;
}
</script>
```

Comment: share with us what u have tried...

Comment: check this thread..
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3780040/validating-a-radio-button-is-checked-with-jquery

Answer (score 1):

I have solved the problem with this code 
`if ($('div.quizbox:not(:has(:radio:checked))').length) {
    alert("You missed answering one or more of the questions.");
}`

Comment: Super useful. note: this is jQuery, though - not vanilla Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

try this it works for me

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
         function  validateForm(){
           var inputs = document.querySelectorAll("#option1,#option2,#option3,#option4,#option5,#option6")
           var  formValid  = false;
           for(var i=0;i<inputs.length;i++){
               if(inputs[i].checked){
                   formValid  = true;
                }
           }
          if(!formValid ){
               alert("Must check some option!");
           }
       }
   </script>
```

html code

```
 <body>    
    <form name="frm">        
            Question 1<br>
            <input type="radio" name="group1" value="Ans1" id="option1">Ans1<br>
            <input type="radio" name="group1" value="Ans2" id="option2">Ans2<br>
            Question 2<br>
            <input type="radio" name="group2" value="Ans1" id="option3">Ans1<br>
            <input type="radio" name="group2" value="Ans2" id="option4">Ans2<br>
            Question 3<br>
            <input type="radio" name="group3" value="Ans1" id="option5">Ans1<br>
            <input type="radio" name="group3" value="Ans2" id="option6">Ans2<br>

        <input type="submit" value="Test" onclick="validateForm();" />
    </form>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but the code is still validating only one radio button.

Comment: on my machine it validate all radio buttons try using  var inputs = document.querySelectorAll("input[type=radio]")

Comment: Thank you Sumit! for the help, but when I try to choose one, it validates the form, If I choose 1 out of 3 radio button, a message alert will prompt, if 2 out of 3, a message will also prompt. I must choose 3 radio buttons so that it can process the form action.

Comment: I have solved the problem, I used jquery and with this code 

$('div.question:not(:has(:radio:checked))')  

Thanks for your hlep